# Chaining login and getUser requests in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I’m learning RxSwift and I’d could really use some help here. Basically I want to achieve 4 things:

1. Call login request
2. Save access and refresh tokens
3. Get the user and save him to the database
4. And after all of this is done I want the function to return void (afterwards my app goes to the home screen)

This is what I have now:

```
func login(email: String, password: String) -> Single<Void> {
    return request(type: Auth.self, endpoint: ApiAuthRouter.login(email: email, password: password))
        .do(onSuccess: { [unowned self] auth in
            self.apiService.authenticationManager.setAuthTokens(auth: auth)
            self.getUser()
        }
        .asVoid
}

private func getUser() {
    request(type: UserNew.self, endpoint: ApiUserRouter.me)
        .subscribe(onSuccess: { user in
            self.realmManager.writeSync({ realm in
                realm.add(user, update: .modified)
            })
            self.apiService.authenticationManager.setUser(user: user)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

It does work somewhat, but when I get to the home screen I still don’t have my user, he is fetched in the background. How to chain these requests effectively?

Comment: does this screen dismiss to reveal the home screen?

Comment: Yup, it does indeed

Comment: have you tried calling the getUser function in the viewdidappear of the home screen instead of here? or would that not work?

Comment: In the Home Screen, are you trying to pull the user out of the RealmManager or out of the AuthenticationManger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. A much better way to chain those requests is to use `flatMap` and call `getUser` inside of it and handle the user response in a `do` block. Thanks for help everyone.

```
func login(email: String, password: String) -> Single<Void> {
    return request(type: Auth.self, endpoint: ApiAuthRouter.login(email: email, password: password))
        .flatMap { auth -> Single<UserNew> in
            self.apiService.authenticationManager.setAuthTokens(auth: auth)
            return self.getUser()
                .do { user in
                    self.realmManager.writeSync({ realm in
                        realm.add(user, update: .modified)
                    })
                    self.apiService.authenticationManager.setUser(user: user)
                }
        }
        .asVoid
}

private func getUser() -> Single<UserNew> {
    return request(type: UserNew.self, endpoint: ApiUserRouter.me)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you are trying to pull the User data out of something, either the RealmManager or the AuthenticationManager. At the moment you are trying to pull the data out, it doesn't yet exist.

Rx is a push based system. Don't try to pull data out of things; instead subscribe to the thing and let it push the data.

A great talk on this subject is: [Reactive Programming: Why It Matters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49dMGC1hM1o)